# numpy.loadtxt gives "not iterable" error

Tags: python, input, numpy

I'm trying to use `numpy.loadtxt` to read the data in a file that looks like this:

```
## 14 line of header
3 0 36373.7641026
3 1 36373.7641026
3 2 36373.7641026
...
```

And when I give it this:

```
>>> chunk, power = numpy.loadtxt(bf,skiprows=14,usecols=(1,2),unpack=True)
```

Or even this:

```
>>> power = numpy.loadtxt(bf,skiprows=14,usecols=(2))
```

It says, `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

I assumed it was because the first two columns were clearly integers not float, but now I'm not even sure which int object it's referring, because it won't even read just the floats. How do I make `loadtxt` work?

Related: How do I specify the format of multiple columns using `dtype = ?` I'm having trouble figuring it out via google.

Answer (score 10):

In your second example, the problem is likely `usecols=(2)`. `usecols` must be a sequence. `(2)` is the integer 2, not a one-element tuple containing 2, and is likely what the error message is complaining about: `loadtxt()` is trying to iterate over an `int`. Use `(2,)` (or `[2]` if you prefer).

Comment: usecols is the option specifying which columns to read. See:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.4.x/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html

Comment: @LoonUnit: I certainly understand what `usecols` is, which is why I know it must be a sequence. As I said in my answer, `(2)` is not a sequence, it is the integer 2.

Comment: Okay, friend explained your answer, and it was ultimately correct. usecols=(2,) did work.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know what's causing the problem in this case, because you haven't given us enough information. Given what you've posted here, your code should work:

```
>>> with open('beamtest.out', 'r') as f:
...     f.readlines()
... 
['header 0\n', 'header 1\n', 'header 2\n', 'header 3\n', 'header 4\n', 
 'header 5\n', 'header 6\n', 'header 7\n', 'header 8\n', 'header 9\n', 
 'header 10\n', 'header 11\n', 'header 12\n', 'header 13\n', 
 '3 0 36373.7641026\n', '3 1 36373.7641026\n', '3 2 36373.7641026']
>>> chunk, power = numpy.loadtxt('beamtest.out', skiprows=14,
                                 usecols=(1,2), unpack=True)
>>> chunk
array([ 0.,  1.,  2.])
>>> power
array([ 36373.7641026,  36373.7641026,  36373.7641026])
```

Of course, as [kindall](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10758854/577088)'s answer indicates, your second example will fail because `usecols` doesn't accept single integers; it [requires a sequence](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html). (`(1)` is just `1` in parenthesis; to create a tuple, you need a comma in there -- `(1,)`.)

Here is an example of how to use `dtype` to specify the format of multiple columns:

```
>>> record = numpy.loadtxt('beamtest.out', skiprows=14, usecols=(1, 2), 
                           dtype={'names':('chunk', 'power'), 
                                  'formats':('i8', 'f8')}) 
>>> record
array([(0, 36373.7641026), (1, 36373.7641026), (2, 36373.7641026)], 
      dtype=[('chunk', '<i8'), ('power', '<f8')])
>>> record['chunk']
array([0, 1, 2])
>>> record['power']
array([ 36373.7641026,  36373.7641026,  36373.7641026])
```

Comment: bf is just a filename, bf = "beamtest.out"

Comment: @LoonUnit, look at my edit. It at least answers the second part of your question (about `dtype`). I tested your first example, and it should work perfectly.

Comment: yeah, I think I'm going to end up using your answer in the long run.